# Is it possible to have a detached TpFIBDataset for FIBPlus?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009, fibplus

I remember that when I was working with `ADO` for `Delphi` (`dbGo`) there was a possibility of creating a detached dataset. The idea was that I could read all the data which I wanted from database and then set the connection property to nil. That caused `TADOQuery` to work as a memory table. I could then use and pass `TADOQuery`as a `TDataSet` parameter to my other methods without worrying that I am keeping unnecessary connection or transaction opened.

I would like to have the same functionality when using FIBPlus library. Currently I need to copy data from `TpFiBDataset` to other structure and then close the data set. Otherwise to access the rows of dataset, transaction must stay opened, even if I have all the data fetched.

I could not achieve detached dataset functionality on my own, is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

No. TpFIBDataSet could not work as a standalone dataset. You should use TpFIBClientDataSet (if you want to apply later updates to db) or any TInMemoryDataSet (just for local reading).